# How to set mouse wheel tilt click support up?

Tags: mouse

My new mouse (Logitech RX250) supports a new feature - scroll wheel tilt: it feels like clicking if I lean the wheel to the left or to the right. But it does nothing. I would like to set it up to do do something (act like <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> for example). How to do it?

Comment: Are you sure it does nothing? I think the default in Ubuntu is to provide horizontal scrolling.

Comment: I'll check this, @gertvdijk.

Comment: Can you try to run 'xev' (trace X events) from a terminal?  Then place your mouse cursor on the square in the window that opens, then do the wheel tilt inside the square.  Does it produce an event?  If so, what's the keycode? With xmodmap (man xmodmap) you should be able to convert the numeric keycode to a symbolic keysym that can be acted on by your window manager.

Comment: Check [this](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Mice-and-Pointing-Devices/Guide-for-setup-Performance-MX-mouse-on-Linux-with-KDE/td-p/517167) thread out.  Its not the exact same mouse but it has a tilt wheel.

Comment: All of you are right, guys. 1. it does horizontal scrolling by default. 2. `xev` helps to find out that tilt clicks work as buttins #6 and #7 (for left and right tilt respectively). 3. the article linked answers the question of how to customize the behaviour. So, somebody, submit this information as an answer and get the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: For Russians interested in the subject, here is a related article in Russian: http://habrahabr.ru/post/160101/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

Install xbindkeys: `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys`
Install xte: `sudo apt-get install xautomation`

create the xbindkeys config file `xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`

now run `xev`, put your mouse in the box and click the button you want to map.
You should get something like

```
  ButtonRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4400001,
    root 0x2e9, subw 0x4400002, time 21579213, (28,34), root:(818,86),
    state 0x110, button 1, same_screen YES
```

In this case "button 1" is the number of the button we want to map.
Now we need to edit xbindkeys config file.
`gedit $HOME/.xbindkeysrc`
Scroll to the bottom of the file and create a new line.
If you want to bind 'button 1' to the 'home' key type:

```
"xte 'keydown Home' 'keyup Home'"  
b:1
```

[image]

Now make xbindkeys start on startup.  Open startup applications. Click 'Add' put xbindkeys in the 'name' field and  `/usr/bin/xbindkeys` in the 'Command Field'.

[image]

Restart the computer.

That will bind 'button 1' to the 'home' key.